# How to insert space before the last 3 characters in a string C#?

Tags: c#

I am using windows forms and I am building application where the users enter their UK PostCode.

The UK PostCode contains space before the last 3 characters, examples like:

`L22 9QY` , `L5 3SG` , `WA10 4RT` so there is always space just before the last 3 characters. What I am trying to do is: when a user enters their PostCode like this `L53SG` I want to insert space before the last 3 characters to make it like this `L5 3SG`.

Say we have:

```
string PostCode = "L53SG";
```

how do I insert space before the last 3 characters in PostCode string?

Anyone knows how to do that. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
postCode = postCode.Replace(" ", "");
if (postCode.Length > 3)
    postCode = postCode.Insert(postCode.Length - 3, " ");
```

First remove any spaces that are there, then make sure there are at least 3 characters (we may want to throw an exception in this case as it's not a valid input for the rest of your use) and insert a space 3 spaces back.

It's possible to see if the user entered a space and skip the process if they did, but this way is simpler and catches the case where the user added one in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `string.Insert` and `string.Length` to do that easily:

```
string insertedStr = str.Insert(str.Length - 3, " ");
```

The `string.Length` will return the length of your `string` and by subtracting it by 3, you can get the index position where you want to insert your `space`.

Finally, you only need to use `string.Insert(index, value)` to insert the replacement `string` (in your case being space (`" "`))

Answer (score 3):

If you want you can first remove any space in the string:

```
PostCode = PostCode.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Then, use `Insert()` method:

```
string PostCode = "L53SG";
PostCode = PostCode.Insert(PostCode.Length - 3, " ");
```

Comment: When I lived in the UK I would always have entered my postcode with the space in there. Apply this code, and now there are two spaces.